# jquery vertical mousewheel smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling, parallax.js

I'm making a parallax website and I would like to make the page scroll smoother with the mousewheel for a better user experience.
The best example I could get was this website: http://www.milwaukeepolicenews.com/#menu=home-page
It would be great if I could get something similar to that into my website, the smooth vertical scrolling and scroll inertia.

I noticed they are using Brandon Aaron's jQuery mousewheel which is very light but I'm just a beginner and cannot make it work by myself.

Also i noticed this in their mpd-parallax.js:

```
jQuery(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
        if(delta < 0) page.scrollTop(page.scrollTop() + 65);
        else if(delta > 0) page.scrollTop(page.scrollTop() - 65);
        return false;
    })
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I'm almost there. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmelcul/cZuym/ It only needs adding an easing method to scroll just like the Milwaukee Police website.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far - its hard to make suggestions otherwise.

Comment: It really needs easing, it's kinda jerky in Firefox and Chrome, but strangely it works extremely well and smooth in IE10.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142490/smooth-scrolling-easing-effect-with-mouse-wheel?lq=1

Comment: @gigimelcul Can you post your entire solution (with the easing method) as an answer? I'll be glad to vote up, since this appears to work quite well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542586/javascript-smooth-parallax-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel

Answer (score 18):

I know it's a really old post, but here is a good solution I made :

```
function handle(delta) {
    var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
  var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

    if (end == null) {
    end = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
  end -= 20 * delta;
  goUp = delta > 0;

  if (interval == null) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
      if (scrollTop <= 0 || 
          scrollTop >= $(window).prop("scrollHeight") - $(window).height() ||
          goUp && step > -1 || 
          !goUp && step < 1 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        end = null;
      }
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop + step );
    }, animationInterval);
  }
}
```

Test it : http://jsfiddle.net/y4swj2ts/3/

Answer (score 10):

Here are two jsfiddles -- one with the script and one without it so you can compare:

- [with script](http://jsfiddle.net/47cDN/)
- [without script](http://jsfiddle.net/2XJR9/)

JavaScript using the [jQuery mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = $('#content');  // set to the main content of the page   
    $(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
        if (delta < 0) page.scrollTop(page.scrollTop() + 65);
        else if (delta > 0) page.scrollTop(page.scrollTop() - 65);
        return false;
    })
});
```

Compare the two. From what I can tell, the script slows the mouse wheel so it requires more physically turning to scroll the same distance as without the script. It may feel smoother because of that slower scrolling (and it may indeed be smoother as it is probably easier on the graphics unit).

Comment: You can make it scroll using arrow keys as well (and it would be more user-friendly to scroll using arrow keys as well as the mouse wheel). http://jsfiddle.net/aVvQF/4/

Comment: @DavidMartins I prefer it without too but that wasn't the question :).

Answer (score 5):

Check out [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/). It's a plugin to create the parallax effect. It has options when you initialize the plugin to toggle smooth scrolling:

```
var s = skrollr.init({
    smoothScrolling: true,
    smoothScrollingDuration: 1800
});
```

Answer (score 4):

hey I got another ressource here which is really simple to use [smoothwheel](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel)

It enable a smooth scroll animation on mousewheel on every devices and work perfectly !

Comment: Unfortunately, neither the demo at the SmoothWheel site nor the "working demo" you link at the end work at all in Chrome 39. The scrolling is still the regular block jump when moving the wheel a notch. The "skrollr" library mentioned above, on the other hand, does work in Chrome 39

Answer (score 3):

I found this plugin, it has some nice options and works on all major devices http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Comment: It does more than just smoothening the scrolling process. It also adds a nice custom scrollbar to the page. Cons: slower than other simpler implementations for smooth-scrolling, and also a little heavier in size too.

Comment: Not smooth at all. It causes the page to shake as you scroll. Absolutely horrible!

Comment: link isbroken..here is the latest one https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/