# jQuery parallax lags inChrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, parallax

My parallax effect works well in firefox, but in chrome and safari it doesn't work well. Here's a [jsfiddle.net/n5kjK/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/n5kjK/1/) that describes the structure of my page.

My HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=thumbnail"/>
    </div>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet leo non erat aliquam pellentesque. Duis et dictum velit. Curabitur blandit odio quis luctus ultrices. Maecenas venenatis erat in eros feugiat imperdiet. Duis ultricies nulla quis eros eleifend sagittis.
</article>
<article>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=thumbnail"/>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet leo non erat aliquam pellentesque. Duis et dictum velit. Curabitur blandit odio quis luctus ultrices. Maecenas venenatis erat in eros feugiat imperdiet. Duis ultricies nulla quis eros eleifend sagittis.
</article>
<article>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=thumbnail"/>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet leo non erat aliquam pellentesque. Duis et dictum velit. Curabitur blandit odio quis luctus ultrices. Maecenas venenatis erat in eros feugiat imperdiet. Duis ultricies nulla quis eros eleifend sagittis.
</article>
<article>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=thumbnail"/>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet leo non erat aliquam pellentesque. Duis et dictum velit. Curabitur blandit odio quis luctus ultrices. Maecenas venenatis erat in eros feugiat imperdiet. Duis ultricies nulla quis eros eleifend sagittis.
</article>
<article>
    <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200&text=thumbnail"/>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet leo non erat aliquam pellentesque. Duis et dictum velit. Curabitur blandit odio quis luctus ultrices. Maecenas venenatis erat in eros feugiat imperdiet. Duis ultricies nulla quis eros eleifend sagittis.
</article>
```

My JS

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
        $('.ciao').html("ciao");
        var windowScrollTop=$(this).scrollTop();
        parallax(windowScrollTop);      
    }); 
});

function parallax(windowScrollTop) {
    $('.thumbnail-container img').each(function(index){
    var dif=windowScrollTop-$(this).parent().position().top;
        var scrollSlow = dif *(0.5);
        if(dif>=0)
            $(this).css('top', (scrollSlow) + 'px');
     });
}
```

and my CSS

```
article{
    width:100%;
    text-align:justify;
}
.thumbnail-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.thumbnail-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work well"?

Comment: scroll is glitching on google chrome and safari.

Comment: What does "glitching" mean?  I'm running your fiddle in Chrome and it looks fine.

Comment: I think I see it.  Do you mean the checkerboarding texture whenever you scroll really quickly?  If so, there may not be anything you can do on your end without changing how you do the parallaxing, consider: [Fix Checkerboard Scrolling Problem in Google Chrome](http://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/fix-checkerboard-scrolling-problem-google-chrome/)

Comment: I think he is referring to it being a choppy animation and not smooth.

Comment: Yes, but in Firefox it works very well. Even if I follow the [guide](http://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/fix-checkerboard-scrolling-problem-google-chrome/), the animation is choppy in Chrome

Comment: Its only a problem scrolling with the mousewheel.  check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542586/javascript-smooth-parallax-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel

Comment: @DavidStetler if you make an answer with your comment I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the mouse scroll is not smooth. [Use this plugin](http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/) to override default mouse scroll.