# How to create a nice & smooth scrolling effect on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The default scrolling effect of all the browsers is jumpy. How can I give my website a nice and smooth scrolling effect with jquery?

Comment: Please search before you ask.  Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905779/jquery-vertical-mousewheel-smooth-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin works pretty well.

```
$('#myElem').scrollTo('#someOtherElem', time, onfinishedcallback(){});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/GHhyW/)