# jQuery smooth scroll entire page

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

somebody know how to make a smooth mouse scroll, like this page?
http://www.werkstatt.fr/#/project/dior-addict

I've already searched the web, but cannot find any good solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From Cymen's answer on stack overflow, [jquery vertical mousewheel smooth scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905779/jquery-vertical-mousewheel-smooth-scrolling)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page = $('#content');    
    $(window).mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
        if (delta < 0) page.scrollTop(page.scrollTop() + 65);
        else if (delta > 0) page.scrollTop(page.scrollTop() - 65);
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: thnx for answer, but it didn't work... i found in the same question on stack the answear that works for me, here it is: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/