# How to make scrollbar invisible in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, webkit

I'm looking for a way to make the scrollbar invisible in Firefox. That is, you shouldn't be able to see it, but you should still be able to scroll. For other browsers, this works:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
```

However, it seems that this feature has been removed from Firefox. Surely someone has found a workaround just for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide scroll bar, you will need the CSS

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;"> ...</body>
```

I am wondering, if scroll bar will not be available to your page, how your content is going to be read fully. By the way, this CSS works will all elements like `<div></div>` etc. too.

For scrolling you will need to add `scroll` event. Take [a reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905779/jquery-vertical-mousewheel-smooth-scrolling) for scroll event handling.

Comment: Hidden overflow removes the ability to scroll entirely, whereas I'm looking for the option to hide the scrollbar while maintaining scroll functionality.

Comment: Yes that is right. If you add `scroll` event handler to `<body>` element, than mouse wheel up.down, will be able to scroll the page.

Comment: There is very good answer in stack overflow [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll). I hope it will solve what you are looking for.