# How do I make scrolling smoother?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I really want to customize the scrolling on a webpage I'm working on. I've been browsing the internet for a long time now trying to find a way to make the scrollbar glide instead of jump every time you move the scroll wheel. I know how to customize the scrollbar itsself to change its appearance, but I can't figure out how to change the functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable smooth scrolling for my website in all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349245/enable-smooth-scrolling-for-my-website-in-all-browsers)

Comment: Download Opera, and the scrollbar will glide