# Scroll function doesn't produce a smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 1 fixed DIV `#scroll-up` that is 100% height of the browser window. I have another DIV `#next-prev` that sits underneath it. As soon as `#next-prev` comes into view I want the `#scroll-up` DIV to begin scrolling up. My code blow does this, however as soon as `#next-prev` is in view `#scroll-up` just jumps up for no reason. The effect should be seamless.

How do I prevent the jump?

**I have setup a demo of the problem on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sya0jr6p/1/**

---

**JS**

*Uses the [jQuery Visible plugin](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) to detect when #next-prev is in view.*

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($('#next-prev').visible(true)) {
        console.log ( '#next-prev visible' );

        // Initiate scroll up of '#scroll-up' when '#next-prev' is in the viewport
        var $tagline = $('#scroll-up');
        var windowScroll;

        // Function
        function slidingTitle() {

            //Get scroll position of window
            windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

            $tagline.css({
                'top' : -(windowScroll/3)+"px"
            });

        }
        // Initiate
        slidingTitle();

    } else {
        console.log ( '#next-prev not visible' );
         // The element is NOT visible, do something else

    }

});
```

**UPDATE**

After further testing the jump ONLY exists when `#nav-wrap` isn't already on the screen. If it is on the screen then the jump doesn't occur and works as expected.

Another thing I noticed; When you first load the page AND `#nav-wrap` isn't already on the screen. Scroll down the page as normal until you see `#scroll-up` jump up and if you continue scrolling down you'll see what I want to happen. `#scroll-up` scrolling normally. BUT if after the jump has taken place you scroll back up the page to the very top, you'll notice the position of `#scroll-up` isn't the same as when you first loaded the page. Could the calculation wrong? or could the order of the code be wrong? Just a few ideas...

**UPDATE**

This is a animated GIF of how I want the scroll to work, the animate answers that have been given aren't intuitive:

[image]

Comment: Is that better on your side using `animate()`: http://jsfiddle.net/sya0jr6p/2/  ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm afraid not, i'd like it to move smoothly on scroll if possible.

Comment: But for me on chrome it moves (quite) smoothly. Now you could debounce a little your scroll handler. Search for throttle/debounce scroll event (using a timer)

Comment: @A.Wolff Do you see the #scroll-up div jump up when the next-prev div comes into view? Only after then does it scroll smoothly. I need to be smooth all the time

Comment: @A.Wolff Its just an unnatural animation. Animate only plays when you finished scrolling. Its much better if the user sees it move with the scroll in my opinion.

Comment: @egr103 hi for bouncing back or what you are saying div jump up is due to the css for **#next-prev** selector in which you have given the clear:both remove that it will not jump up and scroll

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara Thanks but I'm afraid it does still jump

Comment: @egr103 it shold not but can't say about that

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara Please see updated question

Comment: @egr103 Obviously it's the code mistake of your that while scrolling down it sets the top to the like in minus for Example **top:-173.88877**

Comment: @egr103 I just posted a solution.  Let me know if thats the functionality you were looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see the jump is that you simply divide the current window scroll position once the `#next-prev` comes into view by 3 and set that as a top value for `#scroll-up`... the window scroll when you reach `#next-prev` will be larger than 0, hence the scroll divided by three will also be larger than zero, and `#scroll-up` will immediately get a (large) negative `top` value.

I don't know where you got the division by three from - that would create a slower scrolling of the element (aka. parallax effect) - which means that even if there was no jump and `#scroll-up` started to scroll at the right point, it would still cover two thirds of `#next-prev` once `#next-prev` was fully in view... So I don't think you actually want the parallax effect...

What I think you want is:
The `top` value of `#scroll-up` needs to be zero until the first pixel of `#next-prev` scrolls into view, and then grow gradually as `#next-prev` comes "more" into view, making sure it stays exactly above `#next-prev`... ie. the top of `#scroll-up` needs to be 0 minus the number of pixels `#next-prev`'s top is from the bottom of the viewport - and of course always zero if `#next-prev` is still completely below the viewport.

Here's a way to achieve that...

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //Get the footer position relative to the document
    var footer_offset = $("#footer").position().top;
    //Get the window height (viewport height)
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    //Get the current scroll position
    var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    //Calculate the bottom of the window relative to the document
    var window_bottom_offset = window_scroll + window_height;
    //Calculate "how much" of the footer is above the bottom of the window
    var footer_visible_pixels = window_bottom_offset - footer_offset;
    //Default #semistuck's position to top: 0px
    var semistuck_top = 0;
    //But if the footer is above the bottom of the screen...
    if (footer_visible_pixels > 0) {
      //...move #semistuck up by the same amount of pixels
      semistuck_top = -footer_visible_pixels;
    }
    //Actually move it
    $("#semistuck").css('top', semistuck_top + 'px');
    //Just to see each step of the calculation
    console.log(footer_offset, window_height, window_scroll, window_bottom_offset, footer_visible_pixels, semistuck_top);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
#semistuck,
#loooooong,
#footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#semistuck {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #afa;
}
#loooooong {
  height: 2000px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 100px, #465298 100px, #465298 200px);
}
#footer {
  background: #faa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="semistuck">
  This is stuck until the<br>footer scrolls into view
</div>
<div id="loooooong"></div>
<div id="footer">
  When this gets into<br>view #semistuck will<br>get out of its way
</div>
```

Obviously the above code is way more verbose than needed, but I felt that very small increments in the calculation makes it clearer what happens....

Here's the same thing in a shorter form:

```
var footer_visible_pixels = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $("#footer").position().top;
$("#semistuck").css('top', (footer_visible_pixels > 0 ? -footer_visible_pixels : 0) + 'px');
```

### Hmm...

...come to think of it you may actually want the parallax effect, but just want the footer to be on top, so here's a slightly modified version which gives a somewhat cool effect:

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //Get the footer position relative to the document
    var footer_offset = $("#footer").position().top;
    //Get the window height (viewport height)
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    //Get the current scroll position
    var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    //Calculate the bottom of the window relative to the document
    var window_bottom_offset = window_scroll + window_height;
    //Calculate "how much" of the footer is above the bottom of the window
    var footer_visible_pixels = window_bottom_offset - footer_offset;
    //Default #semistuck's position to top: 0px
    var semistuck_top = 0;
    //But if the footer is above the bottom of the screen...
    if (footer_visible_pixels > 0) {
      //...move #semistuck up by the same amount of pixels
      semistuck_top = -footer_visible_pixels/3;
    }
    //Actually move it
    $("#semistuck").css('top', semistuck_top + 'px');
    //Just to see each step of the calculation
    console.log(footer_offset, window_height, window_scroll, window_bottom_offset, footer_visible_pixels, semistuck_top);
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
#semistuck,
#loooooong,
#footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#semistuck {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #afa;
}
#loooooong {
  height: 2000px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 100px, #465298 100px, #465298 200px);
}
#footer {
  background: #faa;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="semistuck">
  This is stuck until the<br>footer scrolls into view
</div>
<div id="loooooong"></div>
<div id="footer">
  When this gets into<br>view #semistuck will<br>get out of its way
</div>
```

Only two things are changed compared to the original suggestion:

1. I've added `position: relative` to the footer
2. I divide the negative `top` of `#semistuck` by three

### Note

None of this will work on iPhones, iPads, and probably most other touch devices. They simply don't fire any scroll events *during* scroll, but only *after*. So if support for mobile devices is a concern, you should detect those and provide a fallback - the alternative is a very jumpy effect that happens only after scrolling ends. To the best of my knowledge there is no workaround, and depending on the scenario the best way to handle it may be to:

1. just degrade to something simpler
2. use one of the animated solutions provided in the other answers - but only on devices that do not support continuous scroll events

Comment: This is incredibly detailed and makes so much sense! I've got both code snippets (normal scrolling and parallax, the latter being really cool) working in my page. Thanks very much! The only thing is the shorthand version didn't work. I had to use the verbose code, which worked perfectly.

Comment: @egr103 I don't know if it's relevant to your use case, but I just added a note about mobile devices to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Hi need feed back whether **it's your expected result or not.? or what you need to improve**

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var $scrollUp = $("#scroll-up"),
        $nextDiv = $("#next-prev"),
        $divScrolled = $(this).scrollTop()/3;
    if ($nextDiv.visible(true)){
        $scrollUp.stop().animate({
            'top': - $divScrolled
        },'slow');
    }else{        
        $scrollUp.stop().animate({
            'top': 0
        },'slow');
        console.log("Nothing will be in your");
    }    
});
```

```css
html,body{ height:100%; }
#scroll-up {
    position: fixed;
 top: 0;
    background:aqua;
    height:100%;
 left: 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    width: 50%;
}

.demo-purposes { padding-top:200px;}

#next-prev { 
    background:pink; 
    text-align:center; 
    width: 100%;
    top: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative; }
```

```html
<div id="scroll-up">
    <div class="demo-purposes"> <!-- This is just here so you can see the problem -->
        This content block should begin to scroll up when #next-prev is in the viewport. This does happen, however it isn't very smooth and this message will jump up a certain amount of pixels.</div>
</div>
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
<div id="next-prev">
    #next-prev DIV
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing s</p>
</div>
```

here i also give my working jsfiddle so that you can give clear feedback.

[My Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sya0jr6p/4/)

Comment: Please see GIF added to show you what I'm looking for. The solution you have provided doesn't feel intuitive to the scroll. I'd like to keep my effect but simply remove the jump. I urge you to see the jsfiddle I've created that reproduces this jump I refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
Currently you are changing the top value of CSS. Why don't you add a transition to the change in top? See the fiddle example.

```
$tagline.css({
                    'top' : -(windowScroll/3)+"px",
                    'webkit-transition-property': 'top',
                    'webkit-transition-duration': '.5s'
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vq94s6fw/

Comment: This, like with the animate solution, seems to only scroll up when you're finishing scrolling using the mouse. My solution scrolls at the same time you scroll making it more seamless, I'd just like to remove that pesky jump.

Comment: reduce the duration to 0.1s.

Comment: Although a far better solution this still produces a weird, unatural animation when the #nav-wrap div comes into view

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working the way you want it to work.  Let me know if this isn't the case.  I changed the #scroll-up in CSS and added an extra class called .scroll-up-fixed.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/poj3ce51/

```
#scroll-up {
    position: absolute;
    background:aqua;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    width: 50%;
}

.scroll-up-fixed {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

I also changed the jQuery portion to the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#next-prev').visible(true)) {
        console.log ( '#next-prev visible' );

        var $tagline = $('#scroll-up');
        var windowScroll;

        $tagline.removeClass("scroll-up-fixed");

        // Functional parallaxing calculations
        function slidingTitle() {

            //Get scroll position of window
            windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            $tagline.css({
                'top' : (windowHeight)+"px"
            });

        }
        slidingTitle();

    } else {
        console.log ( '#next-prev not visible' );
         // The element is NOT visible, do something else
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The scroll jump is a browser default behaviour of your current browser. (unless you override it)

If you check that with firefox or in EI9+ you will see a smooth scroll.

Chrome has a setting called smooth scroll under [chrome flags](http://chrome://flags/). ( If you are using using chrome )

Search how to force smooth scroll on browsers.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349245/enable-smooth-scrolling-for-my-website-in-all-browsers) might help.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant as I've checked in Firefox and the jump still exists.