# is it possible to scroll browser content smoothly without replacing the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, smooth-scrolling

is it possible to scroll browser content smoothly without replacing the scrollbar - something like behaviour in this example:

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/full_page_demo.html

but without removing the original browser scrollbars - just the smooth content movement

all plugins that I have checked helped to smooth mousewheel-page-scroll or jump-to-link-scroll, but I'm looking for smoothing of the move when dragging the build-in browser scrollbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable smooth scrolling for my website in all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349245/enable-smooth-scrolling-for-my-website-in-all-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You can try : [Simplr-SmoothScroll](https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll)

```
$(function () {
  $.srSmoothscroll({
    // defaults
    step: 55,
    speed: 400,
    ease: 'swing',
    target: $('body'),
    container: $(window)
  })
})
```

Comment: it works fine, but only on mouse wheel scroll, I'm looking for something working when dragging browser scrollbar

Comment: @Picard It's impossible, you need to make your own scrollbar.

Comment: that's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure :( thanks for the answer :)