# Add bounce effect to scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling experience **with* a bounce effect when the user over-scrolls, i.e. scrolls too much to the bottom or top. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110360/4861207) answers how to scroll smoothly, but I'm also trying to bounce when it scrolls out of bounds. Something like this:

Note. Although this gif shows for mobile, I want to implement that for all browsers, desktop and mobil.

[image]

I tried adding the following code to the interval:

```
// 50 = Padding
if (tgt.scrollTop < 50 || tgt.scrollTop > tgt.scrollHeight - tgt.offsetHeight - 50) {
    pos = Math.bounce(step++, start, change, steps);
} else {
    pos = Math.easeOut(step++, start, change, steps);
}
```

But it doesn't give the desired effect. It doesn't bounce at the correct scrolling time, and the bounce isn't real looking, it's not big enough.

(I'm looking for something like [this effect](http://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/), but I want to create it myself, and understand the code.)

How can I create a bouncing effect when the scroll goes to the top or bottom?

I don't want answers with a link to a complex library because I want to create it myself. And I want vanilla JavaScript.

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

/* Smooth scroll */
Math.easeOut = function(t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d;
  return -c * t * (t - 2) + b;
};

// Out Back Quartic
Math.bounce = function(t, b, c, d) {
  var ts = (t /= d) * t;
  var tc = ts * t;
  return b + c * (4 * tc + -9 * ts + 6 * t);
};

(function() { // do not mess global space
  var
    interval, // scroll is being eased
    mult = 0, // how fast do we scroll
    dir = 0, // 1 = scroll down, -1 = scroll up
    steps = 50, // how many steps in animation
    length = 30; // how long to animate
  function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser scroll
    clearInterval(interval); // cancel previous animation
    ++mult; // we are going to scroll faster
    var delta = -Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    if (dir != delta) { // scroll direction changed
      mult = 1; // start slowly
      dir = delta;
    }
    for (var tgt = e.target; tgt != document.documentElement; tgt = tgt.parentNode) {
      var oldScroll = tgt.scrollTop;
      tgt.scrollTop += delta;
      if (oldScroll != tgt.scrollTop) break;
    }
    var start = tgt.scrollTop;
    var end = start + length * mult * delta; // where to end the scroll
    var change = end - start; // base change in one step
    var step = 0; // current step
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      var pos;

      // 50 = Padding
      if (tgt.scrollTop < 50 || tgt.scrollTop > tgt.scrollHeight - tgt.offsetHeight - 50) {
        pos = Math.bounce(step++, start, change, steps);
      } else {
        pos = Math.easeOut(step++, start, change, steps);
      }
      tgt.scrollTop = pos;
      if (step >= steps) { // scroll finished without speed up - stop by easing out
        mult = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

    }, 10);
  }
  var myP = document.getElementById('myP');
  myP.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  // window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
})();
```

```css
p {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="myP">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo
  sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero
  sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et.
  Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris
  tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer laoreet faucibus id ut et. Consequat Ut tellus enim ante nulla molestie vitae sem interdum
  turpis. Fames ridiculus cursus pellentesque Vestibulum justo sem lorem neque accumsan nulla. Lacinia Suspendisse vitae libero sem et laoreet risus Sed condimentum Cras. Nunc massa mauris tempor dolor pulvinar justo neque dui ipsum vitae. Lacinia dui
  scelerisque Sed convallis nonummy orci Vestibulum orci tempus</p>
```

Comment: Why not reverse engineer the library you linked in order to understand how they did it?

Comment: It's way too complex for me. I have no idea where the actual part I'm supposed to look at is.

Comment: If you view the github the source code is split up into small modules such as https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/develop/lib/overscroll/bounce.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'm the author of smooth-scrollbar :)

Actually, this question may be much more complex than you've ever imagined. Now I'll show you a basic implement of overscroll bouncing. [Demo](http://codepen.io/idiotWu/pen/EgNdXK)

We're going to use CSS 3d transform to simulate the bouncing effect, so the DOM structure will be:

```
<article class="container">
    <section class="content">
        your content...
    </section>
</article>
```

The first thing to do is to create a render loop that applies transform style into `.content`:

```
function render() {
    content.style.transform = `translate3d(...)`;

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

And now, let's initialize two variables for state recording:

```
let offset = 0;     // final position
let rendered = 0;   // rendered part
```

Then, applying momentum scrolling with a damping factor:

```
const damping = 0.8;

function render() {
    ...
    const dis = offset - rendered;

    // throw away float part
    const next = offset - (dis * damping | 0);

    content.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${-next}px, 0)`;
    rendered = next;
    ...
}
```

By now, we can scroll to the offset we want, but what about the springback?

The magic is reducing `offset` while rendering, therefore the change of `offset` will be like a normal curve - from 0 to highest then falling back to 0:

```
function render() {
    ...
    offset = offset / 2 | 0;
    ...
}
```

Now the `render` function is like this:

```
function render() {
    const dis = offset - rendered;

    // throw away float part
    const next = offset - (dis * damping | 0);

    content.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${-next}px, 0)`;

    rendered = next;
    offset = offset / 2 | 0;

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Hmmm, it looks much nicer now! The last thing is to handle input events(wheel, touch...), here's a simple snippet for wheel events:

```
// wheel events handler
[
    'wheel',
    'mousewheel'
].forEach(name => {
    container.addEventListener(name, evt => {
        const { y } = getDelta(evt);
        const nextScroll = container.scrollTop + y;

        // check if scrolling onto very edge
        if (nextScroll > 0 &&
            nextScroll < container.scrollHeight - container.clientHeight
        ) {
            return;
        }

        evt.preventDefault();

        offset += y;
    });
});
```

Okay, now we got a basic bouncing model. You can check full code on Codepen: http://codepen.io/idiotWu/pen/EgNdXK.

However, there are still dozens of issues to be fixed. For example, since we're not able to detect whether user left the trackpad(like `touchend` event), we can't perform springback like the native one - scrolling back when users moved away from their trackpad. And as a result, you may suffer from shaking when over scrolling.

To avoid shaking, you can set a flag to prevent movement from increasing as [what I have tried](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/develop/src/events/wheel.js#L40). The major idea is to ignore wheel events when it's scrolling back.

===========

As for mobile devices, you can write you own handlers for touch events. But keep in mind that it should not scroll back until you release your fingers, so you may need another flag to keep `offset` from reducing. It would be a bit hard to play with so many states.

FYI: [smooth-scrollbar/touch.js](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/develop/src/events/touch.js#L85)

Comment: i mean it's good enough, but when i set zoom to 90% the bottom bounce doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick try with **Jquery** - works with the mousewheel; the vital points:

- Capture the 'up' mousewheel event
- Increase `margin-top` of element and use `transition` to animate
- Set max value to offset and a time to reset

Check this snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  var more = 20;
  $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      var st = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (st == 0 && more < 160) {
        $('div').css({
          'margin-top': more + 'px'
        });
        more += 20
      } else {
        $('div').css({
          'margin-top': '0'
        });
        more = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('div').css({
          'margin-top': '0'
        });
        more = 0;
      }, 500)
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  height: 400px;
  transition: .3s margin linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

---

Or [**JsfiddleDemo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5sa1fxee/)