# Smooth page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Mac users knows that there is a very soft page scrolling with touchpad. But when you scroll page with a mouse wheel or even with browser scrollbar - page scrolls not soft, but with some breaks. It happens because of scrollTop difference because it renders not every pixel change.

Is there a way to make cross-browser soft page scrolling like touchpad?
I was trying to use this code:

```js
$window = $(window);

if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 90;
  else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

  handle(delta);
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
}

var goUp = true;
var end = null;
var interval = null;

function handle(delta) {
  var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
  var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

  if (end == null) {
    end = $window.scrollTop();
  }
  end -= 20 * delta;
  goUp = delta > 0;

  if (interval == null) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
      var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
      if (scrollTop <= 0 || scrollTop >= $window.prop("scrollHeight") - $window.height() || goUp && step > -1 || !goUp && step < 1 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        end = null;
      }
      $window.scrollTop(scrollTop + step );
    }, animationInterval);
  }
}
```

```css
p:nth-child(10n) {background-color: #d00}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this code works perfectly in Google Chrome and Opera. But Mozilla and Safari don't show similar soft scroll. They are scrolls content too slowly.

Is there another way to make soft page scroll?

Comment: I have tried implementing smooth scrolling cross-browser and cross-platform before, and it's always far from perfect. My advice would be to leave it with native scrolling behaviour, however imperfect it is.You'll find that you'll make it work great in one browser or platform, then discover it's worse-than-native on others. Ever visited a site on a smooth-scrolling Mac that has a smooth scrolling script enabled? It's horrible, and there's no way to test in JavaScript whether it's a smooth Apple pointer device or a jolty Windows pointer device that's being used (well there is, but it's nasty)

Comment: Yep, I understand that. But on my page there is a lot of parallax elements and they are based on scrolls. So when I'm trying to use native scroll event, I cannot catch it to be smooth animated as I need.

Comment: I want a very soft scrolldown animation like with a touchpad

Comment: That was the exact reason why I tried to achieve smooth scrolling too. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel to help making your smooth scroll because Firefox needs a different event for mousewheel.

This plugin help you implementing scrolling effects in all browsers.
Normally, I use TweenMax for my smooth scrolling.

Comment: You can use scrollTo prop from TweenMax where you set the distance you want to scroll. You can calc the distance of your scroll and add to TweenMax, setting an effect for this.
Check their website https://greensock.com/gsap

Answer (score 0):

I hope [Labu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579996/labu) doesn't mind me posting their answer here but you can you not use a light weight plugin instead?

[Here is the answer from a similar post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19686131/6773642)

[Simplr-SmoothScroll](https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll) and [Demo Here](http://simov.github.io/simplr-smoothscroll/examples/) // Initial source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560714/how-to-enforce-a-smooth-scrolling-rule-for-mousewheel-jquery)

Comment: I've seen this plugin before, but it seems not working as I need.

Comment: Does it not scroll smooth enough or does it jump around on a Mac?

Comment: It not smooth at all. It works like default scroll event without any effects.

Comment: Odd, would you like to try [this](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel) and [demo](http://fatlinesofcode.github.io/jquery.smoothwheel/demo/smoothwheel.html)

Comment: Yes, just opened this demo on Chrome Mac. There is no soft smooth effect at all. It just scrolls for every 4-6 pixels per wheel move without any soft animation :( Sametime - if I use touchpad on mac - red squares moves very softly

Comment: Oh I see. Apologies I was not able to help out there. It's all the scripts I know and trust.